# How to install Tegra Android Development Pack on Ubuntu 11.10 (32 bit)

Tags: android, ubuntu, tegra

I downloaded Tegra development pack from the following link with .run extension. But new i do not know how should I run this package for installation. I am new in Ubuntu and this tegra environment.

http://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/tools/files/Tegra/tegra-devpack-1.0-linux-2012-04-10-12749879.run

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 6):

In Ubuntu OS

1. Run Terminal
2. chmod +x yourPackage.run
3. ./yourPackage.run